# Pojo having Clob type data, unable to convert Json to Object type using GSON library

Tags: java, json, hibernate, gson, pojo

I am POJO having Clob type variable. I am converting POJO type json to the POJO type Java Object using GSON library. But unable to convert. It's giving error like **Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface java.sql.Clob**

My POJO Class

```
    import java.sql.Clob;

    public class MyPojo {

        private String name;
        private Clob message;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Clob getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
        public void setMessage(Clob message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

    }
```

Conversion class

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import org.json.JSONException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class SaveClobType {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, JSONException {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String jsonString = "{\"name\" : \"Country\", \"message\" : \"Hello country\"}";

        MyPojo obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyPojo.class);

        System.out.println("Object converted successfully");

    }

}
```

Please anyone can help me for this. Thanks!

Comment: Why Clob is used in POJO? when you can use String for that.

Comment: @ Karthikeyan Vaithilingam, Actually its sample code. In my project I am having requirement of save data in Clob type in database.

Comment: @Laxminarayan You can save as clob though define as String on POJO

Comment: @ Yusuf K. Thanks it worked for me ! But in future may I face any problem working with Hibernate?